# What dependencies should be in to devDependencies in React on production

Tags: reactjs, node-modules

I'm having a problem with the size of node_modules so I'm trying to reduce it as much as possible so my solution right now is to put unused depencies on production after build into devDependencies. So I want to know that in create-react-app What dependencies can I put in devDependencies ?

now dependencies in my **package.json** look like this

```
"dependencies": {
   "@babel/runtime": "^7.13.10",
   "@pathofdev/react-tag-input": "^1.0.7",
   "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
   "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
   "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
   "axios": "^0.21.1",
   "express": "^4.17.1",
   "generate-password": "^1.6.0",
   "jquery": "^3.6.0",
   "react": "^17.0.2",
   "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
   "react-icons": "^4.2.0",
   "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
   "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
   "react-select": "^4.3.1",
   "react-toastify": "^7.0.4",
   "recoil": "^0.3.1",
   "web-vitals": "^1.0.1"
 },
 "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.15.8",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.14.5",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.1.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.2",
    "css-loader": "^6.3.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.3.2",
    "postcss": "^8.2.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^4.1.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.0",
    "webpack": "^5.57.1",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.3.1"
 },
```

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do, and what packages you're using. Please add your `package.json`

Comment: Both dependencies and dev dependencies end up in your node modules folder, I don't really get what you mean by "put unused depencies after build into devDependencies".

Comment: Oh sorry "unused dependencies", It mean dependencies unused on production.

Comment: Still not too sure what the aim is here. To reduce node modules size you can remove unneeded dependencies, swap out dependencies for smaller ones, or implement your own version of a dependency. Moving stuff from dependencies to dev dependencies won't reduce node modules folder size, nor should it affect the size of your production bundle, since that should omit things not needed in prod automatically

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So at a high level `devDependencies` are things like your testing / jest / typescript code or @type files - things which are not needed by your production application. I doubt that your user need to run jest (@testing-library/jest-dom). These are all node packages which are used to compile your code.

`dependencies` are things that your app actually relies on **in production**, so the production application will / should probably not want to have jest installed and won't be running typescript - it only cares about the compiled code i.e. javascript and those packages that the JS requires - axios / express / react etc. You could put all your packages in the dependencies object, but it would slow your application down and maybe open vulnerabilities hence devDependencies.

node_modules contains all these packages if you don't flag.

Your bundled application should have include `--production` flag when running npm install.

Feel free to correct me if i am wrong!

https://nodejs.dev/learn/npm-dependencies-and-devdependencies

Comment: Is there a way to recognize which dependency could be listed as a devDependency or other way around?